# Express Router Middleware acts on unintended routes

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to use Express Middleware to validate that users are authorized for some of my requests. But, some requests do not require any validation. In a router, I have something like this:

```
// Routes that end in /transactions
module.exports = function(router, isAuthenticated, acl) {
  router.post('/transactions', isAuthenticated, acl.isAdminOrFrom, TransactionHandler.transactions.post);

  // Get most recent transactios by general, category, or userId
  router.get('/transactions/:timeStamp', isAuthenticated, TransactionHandler.transactions.findMostRecent);
  router.get('/transactions/categories/:category/:timeStamp', isAuthenticated, TransactionHandler.transactions.category.findMostRecent);
  router.get('/transactions/users/:user_id/:filter/public/:timeStamp', isAuthenticated, TransactionHandler.transactions.userId.findMostRecent);

  // Get the total reps traded on Repcoin so far
  router.get('/transactions/totaltraded', TransactionHandler.transactions.total.get);
```

Notice that the last route I've listed does not have isAuthenticated there. But, putting that middleware in the above routes has made it act in the last one as well. I also tried something like this:

```
  router.use('/transactions/:timeStamp', TransactionHandler.transactions.findMostRecent);
  router.get('/transactions/:timeStamp', TransactionHandler.transactions.findMostRecent);
```

But the middleware still seems to execute on anything that calls router.get(). How can I use my middleware on a per-route basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this could be because `router.post('/transactions', ...` matches before `router.get('/transactions/totaltraded', ...`. You could try to change the ordering so that the latter route definition is before former and see if it makes any difference. Also try to debug which handlers it triggers on a given route.

Comment: Very bizarre, the order did matter. Thanks for the tip.